# GET query to URL using XMLHttpRequest in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, coffeescript

I'm attempting to retrieve a url using XMLHttpRequest directly:

```
req = new XMLHttpRequest
req.onreadystatechange = -> 
  console.log req.readyState
  if req.readyState == 1
    console.log "sending..."
    req.send
  if req.readyState == 4
    handler(req.response, req.status)
req.open("GET", info.srcUrl, true)
req.responseType = "arraybuffer"
```

But I never see the object transitioning beyond the `1` readyState. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the source url of the page you're running this on, and the value of info.srcUrl? Are you retrieving the content from the same hostname/port as the page which runs this code?

Comment: No, this is an arbitrary request to any web server. Specifically, I'm working with images but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @jabalsad - why shouldn't that matter?  The browser won't let you do that.  However, if you want an image use the image tag -- it will let you do that.

Comment: @Hogan I don't necessarily want to display the image on the browser. I'm trying to retrieve a resource from a url and manipulate the data somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to retrieve an arbitrary resource from another source than the server from which you received the running script, you are more than likely hitting a security issue related to Cross Site Scripting.

Except under very limited circumstances, you cannot retrieve resources from any other site but the one that served the page you are currently viewing.

For an explanation, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FSame_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

For the limited circumstances I mentioned above, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control

Further, since you do not appear to provide an error handler for your XMLHTTPRequest, you're more than likely missing the error message which would have informed you why your request had failed.

#### Update

A quick tutorial on XMLHTTPRequest, including how to handle an onError event can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to mention. I am doing this from a chrome extension, and I gave permissions to https://*/ and http://*/. Thanks for the bit about the error handler, that's probably what I missed. It's strange because it works when I use jQuery.get() method.

Comment: Perhaps you can point me to where I should be doing the error handling? I haven't seen an example in the docs that mention it.

Comment: @jabalsad If append a wildcard at the end of your pattern. `http://*/` only matches the root of a website, `http://*/*` matches all http websites. See [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).

Comment: @RobW how can jQuery.get() succeed then?

Comment: @RobW I understand the concept behind CORS. My point is that the GET request using jQuery.get or jQuery.ajax succeeds, but if I perform a request to the same URL using XMLHttpRequest directly, it doesn't succeed. This seems unrelated to CORS because jQuery is simply a wrapper around XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @jabalsad You should put `req.send()` (with parentheses!) at the of your code. Not inside the onreadystatechange event.

Comment: @RobW Ha! Thanks for that :) Noob mistake

Answer (score 0):

Coming from Ruby, I did not realize that there is a subtle but important difference between `req.send` and `req.send()`. As @RobW pointed out in the comments, this method should also not be called in the event handler but at the end of the code.